# How to store and read text on android project?

Tags: android, android-edittext, storage

I'm pharmD student and newly in android development. I create an app to calculate the doses for patient upon specific calculation. now PharmD will input the data then calc.. etc.
I need to make the user can save the patient case in the internal sd then in any time he need to see it can go back for it
So **firstly**; how to store my text

```
EditText r11;
r11 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Result);
r11.setText(
                            "\n------------------" +
                                    "\nInputs" +
                                    "\n------------------" +
                                    "\n\nPatient Name:" + i1 +
                                    "\nGender:" + i4 +
                                    "\nRace:" + i5 +
                                    "\nRoom:" + i2 +
                                    "\nDate:" + i3 +
                                    "\nAge (years):" + n4 +
                                    "\nHeight (cm):" + n5 +
                                    "\nWeight (Kg):" + n6 +
                                    "\nSCR (mg/dl):" + n7 +
                                    "\nTau (hrs):" + n8 +
                                    "\nCss Avg (mg/L):" + n9 +
                                    "\n\n\n------------------" +
                                    "\nAnalysis:" +
                                    "\n------------------" +
                                    "\n\nIdeal Body Weight:" + r8.getText().toString() + "  Kg" +
                                    "\nAdjusted body weight:" + r9.getText().toString() + "  Kg" +
                                    "\nBody Surface Area:" + Html.fromHtml(r10.getText().toString() + "  m<sup><small>2</small></sup>") +
                                    "\nBody Mass Index:" + Html.fromHtml(r12.getText().toString() + "  Kg/m<sup><small>2</small></sup>") +
                                    "\n\n\n------------------" +
                                    "\nDigoxin TDM :" +
                                    "\n------------------" +
                                    "\n\nVolume of Distribution:" + r4.getText().toString() + "  L" +
                                    "\nCockcroft & Gault:" + r1.getText().toString() + "  ml/min" +
                                    "\nCockcroft & Gault(adjusted for BSA):" + Html.fromHtml(r2.getText().toString() + "  ml/min/1.73m<sup><small>2</small></sup>")+
                                    "\nDigoxin (CrCl):" + r3.getText().toString() + "  L/day"+
                                    "\nElimination Rate Constant: " + r5.getText().toString() + "  h<sup><small>-1</small></sup>"+
                                    "\nHalf Life:" + r6.getText().toString() + "  hr"

                    );
```

**Secondly** ; I want to reload it or read it, so the user can find it !.

I know it is basic for android development but I respect any answer can help me in the (**code**)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quickly persist those information you could use android's [sharedpreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) to save key-value pairs of information.

But in this case I would really recommend that you understand the concept of databases, check on this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html). It should take you step by step to achieve the kind of data organization you need.

To quickly illustrate that, (and in a agressive simplification) think of an excel spreadsheet called patients, each line would represent a patient's data, each column would represent those information that you want to store (Race,Room,Date,Age). Those have data types associated to it, Patient Name is a **TEXT** type information, age is an **INTEGER** number (**27** years) but height sounds like a **REAL** (e.g: **1.75** meters) number and so on.